# как выполнить слеш команду от имени бота в Slack

Tags: python, slack

Создал бота, нужно чтобы бот мог запустить приложение Zoom.

client.chat_postMessage(channel='#standup_channal', text="/zoom")
При таком вызове сообщение обрабатывается как текст, а вот как сделать что бы вызывалась именно слеш команда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

никак, нужно использовать Zoom Api